# Nested routing not working in React Router DOM?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a component that is rendering two different

like

in my ProfilePage.tsx

```
<Routes>
            <Route
              path="/"
              element={example jsx}
             />
             <Route
              path="security"
              element={jsx2}

</Routes>
```

in my app.tsx i have

```
      <Route
    path="/*"
    element={
      <RequireAuth>
        <ProfilePage />
      </RequireAuth>
    }
  />
  <Route
    path="/"
    element={
      <RequireAuth>
        <Navigate to="./security" />
      </RequireAuth>
    }
  />
```

However when I go navigate to "/" in my browser it automatically navigates to /security
I want to render a component in "/" and another component in "/security"
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try again after removing * from your path.

Comment: If I remove *, i cannot navigate to /security its blank

Comment: But when the path is `"/"` the `Navigate` navigates you to `"/security"`. What do you want to render on route `path="/"`?

Comment: it navigates me to /security but it doesnt render the element I defind in teh Route path='security'

but if I leave * wild card in it does render the element in /security but cant navgiate to /

Comment: You are trying to render two routes on "/", which isn't valid, so which of `<Navigate to="./security" />` or `element={example jsx}` do you want rendering on `"/"`. It sort of looks like you are trying to implement route protection.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to wrap my nested route like this

```
      <Route
    path="/"
    element={
      <RequireAuth>
        <ProfilePage />
      </RequireAuth>
    }
  >
    <Route
      path="/*"
      element={
        <RequireAuth>
          <Navigate to="./security" />
        </RequireAuth>
      }
    />
  </Route>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use **exactpath** for differentiate between routing. Suppose you only use path = "/security" and path = "/" for rendering different components. And when the api hits "localhost/security", firstly '/' matches with the root component. So it will always loads the component you render on the '/' path.

You can check the details here: https://dev.to/aasthapandey/exact-path-in-react-router-40je

Comment: I'm using react router dom 6 so exatc path doesnt exist

Comment: That linked blog is for `react-router-dom@5`, OP is using v6.

Comment: Please clarify the question first. Are you using protected routing for rendering security component.